# Python for loop error "index out of bounds"

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to iterate through dataframe rows and set a new column to either a 1 or 0 depending on conditions. Up to the if statement works fine, but once the elif section is added it gives me an "index out of bounds error". Any ideas on how to remedy this?

```
low=history.low
high = history.high
history['bottom'] = " "
history['top']=" "

for i in range(len(history)):

    if (low[i] < low[i-1]) and (low[i] < low[i-2]) and (low[i] < low[i+1]) and (low[i] < low[i+2]) :
            history['bottom'][i] = 1
    

    elif (high[i] > high[i-1]) and (high[i] > high[i-2]) and (high[i] > high[i+1]) and (high[i] > high[i+2]):
    
        history['top'][i]=1

    else:
        history['top'][i] = 0
        history['bottom'][i] = 0
```

Comment: Which line does the error refer to?  Can you identify which index it refers to?  Once you have, fix the code to stop using a bad index there.

Comment: Why are you using `len(history)` then indexing `low` and `high`? Are all three of these guaranteed to be the same length? Even if they are what happens when `i` is at the end of the list and you try to index `i + 1`?

Answer (score 0):

One of our error is explained by @Code-Apprentice

Other which I found and I think you are looking for this is that in lines
`history['bottom'][i] = 1` and `history['top'][i]=1` you are trying to change the value of an index which may not be present in it.

For example if `i = 1` then the lines specified above will generate error as index 1 is not present in them. (They only have index 0).

Instead of using index to change values you can use `.append` to add values

Answer (score 0):

It's because this is trying to access an index that doesn't exist. I would like to see more of the code above to know what `history.low` and `history.high` is referring to for the value.

But have you gotten any results before the error?

Also, please explain `len(history)`. In your code there is a history dictionary where you have `history['bottom'] = " "` and `history['top']=" "`, but at the same time you have `low=history.low` and `high = history.high`. What's the difference between these two history objects/variables?

Please show more of your code.